# SQL Full outer join or inner join

Tags: python, sql, join

This is a simple question I assume.
I get new data which I store into a temp-table "Units_temp". I want to join this with the table "Units". They have the same columns and the key is "Client_id"

I want to do something like bellow (I assume I can to some left join together with insert also?)

I have a lot of columns so I would prefer to no have to list all columns in the code if not necessary

I use Python and MS access database

```
strSQL = "SELECT *
FROM Units_temp
FULL OUTER JOIN Units ON Units_temp.Client_id=Units.Client_id"


cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute(strSQL)
```

Table Units_Temp

```
+----------+------+-------+
| Client_id| Name | Units | 
+----------+------+-------+
|  1       |   A  |   12  |
|  2       |   B  |   2   |
|  4       |   D  |   109 |
|  5       |   E  |   13  |
+----------+------+-------+
```

Table Units

```
+----------+------+-------+
| Client_id| Name | Units | 
+----------+------+-------+
|  1       |   A  |   12  |
|  2       |   B  |   2   |
|  3       |   C  |   4   |
+----------+------+-------+
```

Result I would like to have

```
+----------+------+-------+
| Client_id| Name | Units | 
+----------+------+-------+
|  1       |   A  |   12  |
|  2       |   B  |   2   |
|  3       |   C  |   4   |
|  4       |   D  |   109 |
|  5       |   E  |   13  |
+----------+------+-------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Access doesn't support `FULL JOIN`.

If I understand correctly, you have some sort of prioritization query.  If the duplicate rows are really the same, you can just use `UNION`:

```
SELECT ut.*
FROM Units_Temp as ut
UNION
SELECT u.*
FROM Units as u;
```

If this is a prioritization where you want rows from one table to "overwrite" rows from the other, you can use `UNION ALL` with `NOT EXISTS`:

```
SELECT ut.*
FROM Units_Temp as ut 
UNION ALL
SELECT u.*
FROM Units u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Units_Temp as ut
                  WHERE ut.Client_id = u.Client_id
                 );
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon! Works fine. However the database is not updated. I can print the result in python and see that it is combined/joined, but my database is not joined.

Comment: @NewDev . . . If you wanted to change the table, you would need to `INSERT` the rows.  That would be a different question.

Comment: ok, sorry for being unclear. I would like to update table "Units" with the information from "Units_temp" which is new.